# Entity Framework (using In and Select Distinct)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am relatively new to Entity Framework 6.0 and I have come across a situation where I want to execute a query in my C# app that would be similar to this SQL Query:

```
select * from periods where id in (select distinct periodid from ratedetails where rateid = 3)
```

Is it actually possible to execute a query like this in EF or would I need to break it into smaller steps?

Comment: what is the difference between this query and 'select * from ratedetails where rateid = x' ?

Comment: The query was flipped in my post. Please check it again, sorry.

Comment: As mentioned below, you should relealy be using an IN or JOIN and not an IN clause. http://www.gregreda.com/2013/06/03/join-vs-exists-vs-in/, you can find more articles like this one if you google for them. It also makes the sql or lamda much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done but you should really provide a better example for your query. You are already providing a bad starting point there. Lets use this one:

```
SELECT value1, value2, commonValue
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table1.commonValue = table2.commonValue
    // include some more filters here on table2 
)
```

First, its almost always better to use EXISTS instead of IN.

Now to turn this into a Lambda would be something like this, again you provided no objects or object graph so I will just make something up.

```
DbContext myContext = this.getContext();
var myResults = myContext.DbSet<Type1>().Where(x => myContext.DbSet<Type2>().Any(y => y.commonValue == x.commonValue)).Select(x => x);
```

**EDIT - updated after you provided the new sql statement**

Using your example objects this would produce the best result. Again, this is more efficient than a Contains which translates to an IN clause.

Sql you really want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM periods 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ratedetails WHERE rateid = 3 AND periods.id = ratedetails.periodid)
```

The Lamda statement you are after

```
DbContext myContext = this.getContext();
var myResults = myContext.DbSet<Periods>()
    .Where(x => myContext.DbSet<RateDetails>().Any(y => y.periodid == x.id && y.rateid == 3))
    .Select(x => x);
```

Here is a good starting point for learning about lamda's and how to use them.

[Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, as I implied, I'm still learning. I appreciate the reference link also.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have in your `Context` class:

`DbSet<Period> Periods...`

`DbSet<RateDetail> RateDetails...`

You could use some `Linq` like this:

```
var distincts = dbContext.RateDetails
                         .Where(i => i.rateId == 3)
                         .Select(i => i.PeriodId)
                         .Distinct();

var result = dbContext.Periods
                      .Where(i => i.Id)
                      .Any(j => distincts.Contains(j.Id));
```

**Edit:** Depending on your entities, you will probably need a custom `Comparer` for `Distinct()`. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94272/A-Generic-IEqualityComparer-for-Linq-Distinct), and also [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535374/DistinctBy-in-Linq-Find-Distinct-object-by-Propert)

or use some more `Linq` magic to split the results.

Answer (score 0):

this is your second where clause in your query

```
var priodidList=ratedetails.where(x=>x.rateid ==3).DistinctBy(x=>x.rateid);
```

now for first part of query

```
var selected = periods.Where(p => p.id 
            .Any(a => priodidList.Contains(a.periodid ))
            .ToList();
```